# How to verify outgoing HTTP request from python's module?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, curl, multipartform-data

I need to write Python equivalent code for below mentioned working curl(I have replaced the credentials for obvious reason, but it gives back 200 status.).

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://api.lever.co/v1/candidates?dedupe=true&perform_as=user_123' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic token_123' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 58cafa90-7ae4-47db-a144-4e9d430ffc94' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'files[]=@/Users/gaurav/lever_resume.pdf' \
  -F 'emails[]=a@b.com'
```

So, I ended up in writing this snippet.

```
user_email = 'user@domain.com'
admin_id = '20f3975a-543f-4ca8-b215-2f851232a0ad'
client_id = '893728937298'
client_secret = '32032'
file_path = '/Users/ttn/Desktop/a.txt'
file_name = 'a.txt'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
url = "https://api.lever.co/v1/candidates"
files = {
            'files[]': (file_name, open(file_path,'rb')),
    }
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
querystring = {
    "perform_as": admin_id, 
    "dedupe": 'true'
}
payload = {
    'emails[]': user_email
}
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
}

response = requests.post(url, 
                            headers=headers, 
                            params=querystring, 
                            data=payload,
                            auth=auth, 
                            files=files)
req = response.request
# print(curlify.to_curl(req))

print('\n==== Headers', req.headers)
print('\n==== Body', req.body)
print('\n==== form-data', str(req))

print(response.text)
```

**Question**

- Since Python version of Curl is not working(giving 502 error instead of 200), **so How can I compare the two? Can I generate the Curl out of Python's request**`?
- Can someone spot mistake in my Python version? I am suspecting some problem at form-data being passed (to collect evidence, I need answer to above question)

Edit

There seems to be a [curlify](https://github.com/ofw/curlify) package. But It looks like it does not support distinction between `-d` and `-F` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic token_123',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Postman-Token': '58cafa90-7ae4-47db-a144-4e9d430ffc94',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW',
}

params = (
    ('dedupe', 'true'),
    ('perform_as', 'user_123'),
)

files = {
    'files[]': ('/Users/gaurav/lever_resume.pdf', open('/Users/gaurav/lever_resume.pdf', 'rb')),
    'emails[]': (None, 'a@b.com'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.lever.co/v1/candidates', headers=headers, params=params, files=files)

#NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
#reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
#in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.post('https://api.lever.co/v1/candidates?dedupe=true&perform_as=user_123', headers=headers, files=files)oduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.post('https://api.lever.co/v1/candidates?dedupe=true&perform_as=user_123', headers=headers, files=files)
```

> Reference: https://curl.trillworks.com/#python

Comment: This does not work. It leads to same error i.e 502  `<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>`